# pipeline fit takes in 2 parameters only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

this is my code.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import json
import seaborn as sb 
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn import linear_model 
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from scipy.stats import zscore
from Transformers import TextTransformer
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_json('data/train.json', encoding = 'utf-8', dtype = {'description': str})
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
a = TextTransformer('description', max_features=50)
b = TextTransformer('features', max_features=10)
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('feats', FeatureUnion([
        ('description',a ), # can pass in either a pipeline
        ('features',b ) # or a transformer
    ])),
    ('clf', SVC())  # classifier
])
pipeline.fit(df)
```

What i am curious is that i am trying to predict on a target variable df['interest_level']. However, pipeline.fit only takes in 2 parameters which of one would be self. How do i pass in the target variable then?

Another point to note is that i tried pipeline.fit(df, y=df['interest_level']) and it also throws the same exception. I am using the latest version of pandas / numpy / sklearn.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0a34f1c24eca> in <module>()
      7     ('clf', SVC())  # classifier
      8 ])
----> 9 pipeline.fit(df,df['interest_level'])
     10 # pg = {'clf__C': [0.1,1]}
     11 # grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid= pg ,cv = 2)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    266             This estimator
    267         """
--> 268         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    269         if self._final_estimator is not None:
    270             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    232                 pass
    233             elif hasattr(transform, "fit_transform"):
--> 234                 Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
    235             else:
    236                 Xt = transform.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name]) \

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    495         else:
    496             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 497             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    498 
    499 

TypeError: fit() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: In a classification scenario, typically all scikit learn estimators fit() will take in atleast two parameters: X,y. You are only passing one: df. Change it to something like: X=df[index of independent column, features], y=df[index of target column]

Comment: That's what I tried but it gave me multiple arguments exception

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace

Comment: @VivekKumar I have done so

Answer (score 2):

You are right according to the documentation:

[pipeline: fit()](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/pipeline.py#L242)

you can also check out this example:

[pipeline / featureunion example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-hetero-feature-union-py)

What is the error you're getting exactly?  I would run something like the following:

```
pipeline.fit(df[:, -1], df[:, len(df.columns)]-1)
```

Comment: That example pipeline.fit takes in 2 parameters. That's what I thought it was weird. I did follow it