# Where does class Transformers come from?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

- [***This question***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43012227/2336654)
- [***And this one***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43013565/2336654)
- [***This one too***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291269/using-sklearn-pipeline-and-feature-union)

All show the use of this import

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from Transformers import TextTransformer
```

When I run it

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-6-1f277e1659bb> in <module>()
>       1 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
> ----> 2 from Transformers import TextTransformer
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Transformers
> ```

Googling only led me to the links I've already posted.
Where does `Transformers` come from?

---

```
import sklearn
import sys
print(sklearn.__version__)
print(sys.version)

0.18.1
3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 13:19:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
```

Comment: @jezrael :-) thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second link you provide, it seems to be a user defined file named `Transformers.py` containing class `TextTransformer`.

Comment: Thank you, that was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
pip install transformers
```

The error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Transformers` is because transformers is not installed most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am pretty sure it is some custom file containing transformers, which are very likely inheriting from `TransformerMixin` (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html).

This allows, as shown in the linked questions, to include custom data transformations in a pipeline. For an intro I recommend this great blog post, where also custom transformers are shown: http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html